# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in release but not debug

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, release, exc-bad-access

My product will run fine in debug from xcode to both a simulator and device, but did not run when archived and submitted adhoc. I switched my scheme to run as release, and sure enough, it crashes.

The below portion of code generates an EXC_BAD_ACCESS fault on the `var homeNav` line. This method is in a custom TabBar Controller. I've also included the app delegate call below, as this is where the tabcontroller is created and displayed.

Tab Controller Call:

```
//Sets up view on load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup and add home view
        var homeNav = CMSSNavigationController(navigationBarClass:CMSSNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass:nil)
        homeNav.viewControllers.append(CMSSHomeController(nibName:XIBS.VIEW_HOME, bundle:nil))
        homeNav.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named:Images.TAB_HOME)
        homeNav.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

        //Setup and add profile view
        var profileNav = CMSSNavigationController(navigationBarClass:CMSSNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass:nil)

        profileNav.viewControllers.append(CMSSProfileController(nibName:XIBS.VIEW_PROFILE, bundle:nil))
        profileNav.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named:Images.TAB_PROFILE)
        profileNav.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

        //Set tabs
        self.viewControllers = NSArray(objects: homeNav, profileNav)

    }
```

App Delegate call:

```
 //Handles events after launch
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        //Setup Google Analytics
        GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
        GAI.sharedInstance().dispatchInterval = 20
        //TODO: Set logging level for analytics
        GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId(GoogleAnalytics.TRACKING_ID)

        //Set Window
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

        //Create root tab controller
        var rootControl = CMSSTabBarController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootControl
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();

        return true
    }
```

The code runs fine in release if all UINavigationControllers are declared as `CMSSNavigationController()` without providing a CMSSNavigationBar.

Why would something like this occur in release, but not debug? I see nowhere that would indicate an object or reference is not allocated correctly here.

Comment: Does it die in the CMSNavigationController constructor?

Comment: @KirkSpaziani It's not a custom constructor, so I'm unable to tell precisely. I use default constructor functionality. However, If I attempt to step through using breakpoints it "freezes up" with not discernible action after the var homeNav line (where I set my breakpoint). It runs fine if I do not attempt to set a UINavigationBar class though, so my assumption is it's a constructor issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that the toolbar class in the constructor of a UINavigationController cannot be nil. However, the compiler will not complain about this. And, although I cannot say why, the debug will allow it and run fine, but the release will not.

using the line

```
var homeNav = CMSSNavigationController(navigationBarClass:CMSSNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass:UIToolbar.self)
```

fixes the issue entirely.

Comment: Also, have you submitted a Radar about this? I happened to have this exact problem today as well.

Comment: @A.R.Younce I have not submitted a Radar, but feel free to do so. I'm less versed in how to go about that. I can accept this answer in 1 day.

Comment: Thanks for this! Was facing the same issue. Definitely a bug that directly contradicts their own documentation: "Specify the custom UIToolbar subclass you want to use, or specify nil to use the standard UIToolbar class."